# Plot crossing functions in more explicit format

Tags: plotting

We want to use `Plot3D` for presenting the below functions.

These functions cross each other in some points. How can we plot them to show their crossing more explicitly than the default of *Mathematica*.

```
f[x_,t_]:= Sin[1/2 t (1 + x)]^2;
g[x_, t_] := 1/2 Sqrt[Sin[t (1 + x)]]^2;
Plot3D[{f[x,t], g[x,t]}, {t, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

Comment: You have some bad syntax in there; please check your definitions.

Comment: So sorry, thank you, I corrected that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can generate the arguments of the intersections with `ContourPlot` and grab the result as a `MeshRegion`. This allows us to represent the intersection as `GraphicsComplex`. Finally, we can merge all plots with `Show`.

```
R = Quiet@DiscretizeGraphics[ContourPlot[f[x, t] - g[x, t] == 0, {x, 0, 3}, {t, 0, 4 \[Pi]}]];
S = Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.015], ColorData[97][3],
    GraphicsComplex[ 
     ({x, t} \[Function] {x, t,g[x, t]}) @@@ MeshCoordinates[R],
     MeshCells[R, 1]
     ]
    }];
plot3d = Plot3D[{f[x, t], g[x, t]}, {x, 0, 3}, {t, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, PlotPoints -> 50];
Show[plot3d, S]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A bit less complex (just play with `MeshFunctions`):

```
h = Sin[1/2 y (1 + x)]^2;
g = 1/2 Sqrt[Sin[y (1 + x)]]^2;
Plot3D[{h, g}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, h - g]}, MeshStyle -> {{Thickness[0.015], White}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16, Bold] & /@ {"x", "t"}),
PlotPoints -> 35, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.6]], SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]